# JavaScript LetterGrade function

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function using conditionals, that determines the letter grade from the numerical grade, passed in as a parameter. I have it correctly written in Python, but I am not sure about JavaScript.

In JS, it keeps returning "You made an B", "You made a(n) C", ... , "You made a(n) F", no matter what number I place into the function.

```
function letterGrade(grade) {                   
                if (100>=grade && grade >= 90) {
                        alert('You made a(n) A.');}
                if (80 <= grade && grade< 90) {
                        alert('You made a(n) B.');}
                if (70<= grade && grade < 80) {
                        alert('You made a(n) C.');}
                if (60<= grade && grade < 70); {
                        alert('You made a(n) D.');}
                if (0<= grade && grade < 60) {
                        alert('You made a(n) F.');}
                }

            }
```

Comment: The way you are testing the ranges of values is incorrect for javascript. You would need to expand it out to `100 <= grade && grade >= 90` instead of the pythonic way that you have written.

Comment: FYI, "80 <=grade <90" is interpreted as "(80 <=grade) <90", which is translated into "false <90" or "true <90". Because of weak typing, JS reads this as "0<90" or "1<90". Both of them are true. That's why all your alerts appear

Comment: Given that the conditions are (intended to be) exclusive, consider using `else`.

Comment: It's easier to start by evaluating the lower grades first, too.

Comment: Thank you very much, guys! I see what I did wrong now.

Comment: be a ninja, one line it (just kidding don't, for curiosity only)...                                   "ABCDF"[100%(1+Math.min(Math.max((v), 50), 99))/10|0];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
function letterGrade(grade) {                   
    // singleDigitGrade will be an integer, 1-10
    var singleDigitGrade = Math.floor(grade / 10);

    if (singleDigitGrade === 9 || singleDigitGrade === 10) {
        alert('You made a(n) A.');
    } else if (singleDigitGrade === 8) {
        alert('You made a(n) B.');
    } else if ( singleDigitGrade === 7) {
        alert('You made a(n) C.');
    } else if (singleDigitGrade === 6) {
        alert('You made a(n) D.');
    } else {
        alert('You made a(n) F.');
    }
}
```